# How to solve $\sqrt{\frac{a}{bc+2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca+2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab+2}}\le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c-1}$?

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3.$ Prove that $$\color{black}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{bc+2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{ca+2}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab+2}}\le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c-1}.}$$
> Equality holds at $a=b=c=1.$

***Context.*** I've created accidentally a long time ago.

Originally, I just intended to choose some constant and $(2,3,2,1)$ turns out.

Some previous solvers failed to done because a big trouble is around $a=b=70/43; c=647/6020. $

Indeed, at these specific values, we obtain $ LHS-RHS\approx -0.0004801.$

---

That's why I can not use C-S $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\le \sqrt{3(x+y+z)}$ and $$\sqrt{3\left(\frac{a}{bc+2}+\frac{b}{ca+2}+\frac{c}{ab+2}\right)}\le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c-1}$$ is not true.

Also, the following doesn't help $$\sqrt{(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{ab+2}+\frac{1}{bc+2}+\frac{1}{ca+2}\right)}\le \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot\sqrt{a+b+c-1}.$$
Maybe the Bacteria method helps. We can see [similar question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818134/inequality-frac1-sqrtab2-frac1-sqrtbc2-frac1-sqrtca2-ge)

Inspired by Michael Rozenberg, I've tried $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{(bc+2)(a+k)}\cdot(a+k)}\le \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(bc+2)(a+k)}\cdot (a+b+c+3k)}.$$
Thus, we get $3k=-1 \iff k=-1/3$ which is not valid.

---

Can you help me to optimize this method, especially in some unsual equality cases? It would be great if the solver attach their motivated idea with answer.

I hope to see others better ideas. Also, any ideas improving the question is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Bacteria helps here!

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{bc+2}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(bc+2)(5a+1)}\sum_{cyc}(5a+1)}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(bc+2)(5a+1)}\leq\frac{3(a+b+c-1)}{2(5(a+b+c)+3)}.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$, where $v>0$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$v^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(bc+2v^2)(5a+v)}\leq\frac{3u-2}{2(5u+v)}$$ or
$f(u)\geq0,$ where $$f(u)=80u^2v^8-168uv^9-504v^{10}+60u^3v^4w^3+40u^2v^5w^3-602uv^6w^3-892v^7w^3+$$
$$+685u^2v^2w^6+349uv^3w^6-228v^4w^6-375vw^9+1125uw^9.$$
But $$f'(u)=160uv^8-168v^9+180u^2v^4w^3+80uv^5w^3-600v^6w^3+$$
$$+1370uv^2w^6+349v^3w^6+1125w^9\geq$$
$$\geq4(40uv^8-42v^9+45u^2v^4w^3+20uv^5w^3-150v^6w^3+342uv^2w^6),$$ where the last expression increases as a function of $u$ and by $uvw$ for the proof that $f'(u)\geq0$ it's enough to prove that $$40uv^8-42v^9+45u^2v^4w^3+20uv^5w^3-150v^6w^3+342uv^2w^6\geq0$$ for equality case of two variables.

Let $b=a$ and $c=\frac{3-a^2}{2a}.$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$513a^8-2565a^6-65a^5+1839a^4+130a^3+3797a^2+27a+80\geq0,$$ which is true for $0<a\leq\sqrt3$.

Id est, $f$ increases and by $uvw$ again it's enough to prove $f(u)\geq0$ for equality case of two variables, which gives $$(a-1)^2(75a^7+85a^6-276a^5-248a^4-327a^3-41a^2+1320a+420)\geq0,$$ which is true even for any non-negative value of $a$.

Comment: Thank you. Does $uvw$ help for the last inequality?

Comment: @Dragon boy Yes, of course! It's equivalent to $f(u)\geq0$, where $f$ increases. I am ready to show a full solution. The hardest part it's to prove that $f'(u)\geq0$. I's extremally hard.

Comment: It seems interesting. Hope you show it in your appropriate time.

Comment: Could you show full solution now?

Comment: @Dragon boy  In evening I'll show